# DataSet.GetXml not returning null results

Tags: asp.net, xml, dataset

whenever I convert a DatSet into an XML with DataSet.GetXml, any null value is ignored, so, where i expect this:

```
<value1>a</value1>
<value2></value2>
<value3>c</value3>
```

I get this instead:

```
<value1>a</value1>
<value3>c</value3>
```

Any quick and dirty way to handle this?
Thanks

EDIT:
I think a solution would be using WriteXml. Could anyone provide me with a sample of using it WITHOUT writing to a file but getting a string just like GetXml does? Thanks

Comment: A little tedious approach would be looping through each DataRow and DataColumn in the DataSet and building your own string. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is listed here in the Microsoft KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q317961

The problem is that you have no schema attached to your dataset that specifies that that element should be written out.

I don't believe that using WriteXml will solve the problem, as the documentation states, `"Calling this method is identical to calling WriteXml with XmlWriteMode set to IgnoreSchema."` but you are free to try - here is the equivalent code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ds.WriteXml(sw);
string outputXml = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: What about calling it with XmlWriteMode set to WriteSchema?

Comment: I'll be honest I'm not sure - all that should do is include an inline schema in the output - I doubt it changes the actual XML itself.

Comment: The link above is dead.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine:

```
        //convert to xml with the DataSet schema:
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        string xml = writer.ToString();

        //Convert from xml to DataSet:
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(response);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
```

Comment: This does work but note that the xml in the string literal will still not have elements for the columns consisting of solely null values.