# dataSet.GetXml() doesn't return xml for null or blank columns

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, xsd

When I call dataSet.GetXml() I don't get any xml returned for columns with null or blank values. Is there a simple, efficient way to get around this? An example of the problem below. Notice how a2 is missing from the second results section.

```
<results>
<a1>test1</a1>
<a2>test2</a2>
<a3>test3</a3>
</results>
<results>
<a1>Atest1</a1>
<a3>Atest3</a3>
</results>
```

Comment: What value would *you* put in for a null? Perhaps consider giving the column a default value?

Comment: I would just have the value as blank. I was hoping that there was a way to get all of the xml schema info without having to explicitly set column default values, or do any sort of looping though the xml as I have to do this for many different result sets.

Comment: blank is not the same thing as null

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataSet.GetXml not returning null results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963760/dataset-getxml-not-returning-null-results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is detailed in this Microsoft KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q317961. See this previous SO question for more detail: [DataSet.GetXml not returning null results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963760/dataset-getxml-not-returning-null-results/).

I don't think there is a good solution to your direct question. Given context, there may be another way to approach the problem though.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that worked for me.

First clone the DataTable, make all columns of type string, replace all null values with `string.empty`, then call `GetXml` on a new DataSet.

```
        DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dtCloned.Columns)
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in dtCloned.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtCloned.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dtCloned.Columns[i].ReadOnly = false;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[i].ToString()))
                    row[i] = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtCloned);
        string xml = ds.GetXml();
```

Comment: One edit: If dtCloned.Rows is zero then we should add ->   if (dtCloned.Rows.Count == 0)
                    dtCloned.Rows.Add();

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching the whole world for a solution of writing null fields to XML using DataSet.WriteXML(). I found that following works in a performance optimized way. I have created a function for your convenience. Change your dataset tables one after the other by calling the following function and replacing the tables.

```
    private DataTable GetNullFilledDataTableForXML(DataTable dtSource)
    {
        // Create a target table with same structure as source and fields as strings
        // We can change the column datatype as long as there is no data loaded
        DataTable dtTarget = dtSource.Clone();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtTarget.Columns)
            col.DataType = typeof(string);

        // Start importing the source into target by ItemArray copying which 
        // is found to be reasonably fast for nulk operations. VS 2015 is reporting
        // 500-525 milliseconds for loading 100,000 records x 10 columns 
        // after null conversion in every cell which may be usable in many
        // circumstances.
        // Machine config: i5 2nd Gen, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7 64bit, VS 2015 Update 1
        int colCountInTarget = dtTarget.Columns.Count;
        foreach (DataRow sourceRow in dtSource.Rows)
        {
            // Get a new row loaded with data from source row
            DataRow targetRow = dtTarget.NewRow();
            targetRow.ItemArray = sourceRow.ItemArray;

            // Update DBNull.Values to empty string in the new (target) row
            // We can safely assign empty string since the target table columns
            // are all of string type
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < colCountInTarget; ctr++)
                if (targetRow[ctr] == DBNull.Value)
                    targetRow[ctr] = String.Empty;

            // Now add the null filled row to target datatable
            dtTarget.Rows.Add(targetRow);
        }

        // Return the target datatable
        return dtTarget;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        dc.DataType = typeof(String);
                    }
                }

                DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = string.Empty;
                }
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

Comment: You definitely need to add some explanation to this answer to tell us why you've added this to an already answered question

Answer (score 0):

//////// we need to make a clone of the data set and set all tables' all columns types as string

```
  private static string GetNonNullXMLDataFromDataSet(DataSet dsData, string sNullValueReplacementString)
    {
        string xml = "";
        DataRow drClonned = null;
        DataTable dtCloned = null;

        //////// Make a clone and set all columns as string
        DataSet dsCloned = dsData.Clone();
        foreach (DataTable dt in dsCloned.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                dc.DataType = typeof(string);
                ////dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
            }
        }

        //////// Get data from orignal datatable and create new row in cloned table
        //////// replace DBNull.Value with the provided string marker
        foreach (DataTable dt in dsData.Tables)
        {
            dtCloned = dsCloned.Tables[dt.TableName];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    drClonned = dtCloned.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn dcc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        if (row[dcc.ColumnName] == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            drClonned[dcc.ColumnName] = sNullValueReplacementString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            drClonned[dcc.ColumnName] = row[dcc.ColumnName].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    dtCloned.Rows.Add(drClonned);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                drClonned = dtCloned.NewRow();

                foreach (DataColumn dcc in dtCloned.Columns)
                {
                    drClonned[dcc.ColumnName] = sNullValueReplacementString;
                }
                dtCloned.Rows.Add(drClonned);
            }
        }

        xml = dsCloned.GetXml();
        ////StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        ////dsCloned.ReadXml(sr);
        ////xml = dsCloned.GetXml();
        return xml;

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We need to make a clone of the data set and set all tables' columns types as string.
We also need to handle empty rows so we can generate empty elements against each column for full xml coverage

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer.

Comment: Purpose is to share something working and there is no intention for copy or duplication. if answer is duplicate and not helpful it can be ignored. Thank you.