# getxml() Return null result

Tags: vb.net

```
dim dsXml as new DataSet
dsXml = someMethodthatReturnDatasetValue

dim sXml as string
sXml = dsXml.getXml().toString
```

return result is something like

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<IID>8858</IID>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Remark>g</Remark>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

my expected result is return something like below. but my actual result doesnt return  pair, what should i do to return name pair even my value is null?

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<IID>8858</IID>
<Name></Name>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Remark>g</Remark>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with C#?

Comment: Probably the `Name` column has a `null` value in it.

Comment: yes, the column is null, but i still need the name pair =(

Comment: possible duplicate of [dataSet.GetXml() doesn't return xml for null or blank columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903655/dataset-getxml-doesnt-return-xml-for-null-or-blank-columns)