# Write null fields to xml file from datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string strData = "SELECT * FROM  table";
DataTable dt = Globals.RealsoftObjects.GetDataTable(strData);
dtReportTypes.TableName = "table";
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.WriteXml(sd.FileName,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

I had used this code for write xml file from dataset.
if there is a null value in table it doesn't write on xml.

is there any solution?

for example

table have 2 fields field1 field2
 and field1 is null xml writes only field2 with its value. I need field 1 also.

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832045/dataset-to-xml-null-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code to write xml

```
ds.WriteXml(sd.FileName,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

this will read entire schema

and to convert xml to datatable

```
ds.ReadXml(strFileName,XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```