# Serialising DataSet into XML - missing columns with null values

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

I'm integrating new system with legacy system, part of the requirement is to write cache data in XML format. I've decompiled the legacy system and managed to get as close as possible to the requirement data format.

This is what legacy system does:

```
DataSet formData = getDatasetValuesSomehow();

using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    formData.WriteXml((TextWriter) stringWriter, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
    stringWriter.Flush();
}
```

Output of this looks like this:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet>
        <VALUES diffgr:id="VALUES1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
            <DEBUG_ID>9141c23e-1149-4ba2-b5d1-5c8c77561f0d</DEBUG_ID>
            <DATECREATED>2018-09-24T15:28:00.3769504+01:00</DATECREATED>
            <DATELASTMODIFIED>2018-09-24T15:28:00.3769504+01:00</DATELASTMODIFIED>
            <CREATEDBY>TRAILMAX</CREATEDBY>
            <LASTMODIFIEDBY>TRAILMAX</LASTMODIFIEDBY>
            <TEXT>Oh MY!</TEXT>
            <DATE>2018-09-24T00:00:00+01:00</DATE>
            <INTEGER>42</INTEGER>
            <KEY1 />
        </VALUES>
    </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

That represents all values in a database table row. Note the `<KEY1 />` - this is  a field with `null` value in it.

When I'm doing the very same stuff (as to how I get XML), I only get fields with values in it, no null-fields:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet>
    <VALUES diffgr:id="VALUES1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
      <DEBUG_ID>32ac8a83-a45b-473c-9890-d47a4b274426</DEBUG_ID>
      <TEXT>Hello world</TEXT>
      <DATE>2018-09-30T15:16:13.63+01:00</DATE>
    </VALUES>
  </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

But the table schema is the same, here I should also see `<KEY1 />` and `<INTEGER />` and other fields.

Here is my C#:

```
[Test]
public void Another_Test_ExpectedBehaviour()
{
    var resultDataSet = new DataSet();
    DataTable values = resultDataSet.Tables.Add("VALUES");
    DataRow valuesRow = values.NewRow();
    var recordId = Guid.NewGuid(); // that's just dummy here - I have a value coming from somewhere
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationContext.Current.GetHrnetConnectionstring()))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT top 1 * from DEBUG where DEBUG_ID = @1", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", recordId);
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            var dataRow = dataTable.Rows[0];
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = column.ColumnName;
                object columnValue = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(dataRow[columnName, DataRowVersion.Default]);

                values.Columns.Add(columnName, column.DataType);
                valuesRow[columnName] = columnValue;
            }
        }
    }
    values.Rows.Add(valuesRow);

    // Now get XML
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        resultDataSet.WriteXml(stringWriter, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
        stringWriter.Flush();
        var xml = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I debug through this and look into the final state of `resultDataSet`, I can see that all the columns are available:
[image: All the columns are available int the list of columns when inspected in debug]

But only those with values do come through to XML. How can I show empty columns in XML when deserialised?
Edit: here is legacy system code: https://gist.github.com/trailmax/0100bd6926f311fae277848ce7624e98 - I don't see what I'm doing differently, but they get null-columns and I don't. Only they are on .Net 3.5 and I'm on 4.7.1

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903655/dataset-getxml-doesnt-return-xml-for-null-or-blank-columns) for some ideas.

Comment: look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903655/dataset-getxml-doesnt-return-xml-for-null-or-blank-columns