# How to GetXml from Datagridview in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a problem when using GetXml() to have an XElement from dataset and I am missing some columns which corresponding empty cell values .
the expected result should be like this :

```
<elem>
  <row>
    <col1>val1</col1>
    <col2></col2>
    <col3>val3</col3>
  </row>
</elem>
```

but I am receiving this result instead :

```
<row>
<col1>val1</col1>
<col3>val3</col3>
</row>
</elem>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dataSet.GetXml() doesn't return xml for null or blank columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903655/dataset-getxml-doesnt-return-xml-for-null-or-blank-columns)

Comment: You cannot use the dataset method ReadXml() on complicated xml files.  The results are fractured datatables that cannot be combined that looks like original data.